# sharing ajax data form 1 controler to another in angularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Im learning Angular JS im using a REST api in slim that returns JSON data objects. I have a search controler where i have a submitform method wich gets data. But now i have another controler that also needs this data. now i have read about this and found that it can be don using a factory service but for some reason im getting this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost/c2dmobile/js/main.js:72:23
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:8624:11
    at wrappedCallback (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:6585:59)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:6622:26
    at Object.Scope.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:7769:28)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:7641:25)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:7855:24)
    at done (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:8844:20)
    at completeRequest (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:8984:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js:8954:11) angular-1.0.0.min.js:5525
(anonymous function) angular-1.0.0.min.js:5525
(anonymous function) angular-1.0.0.min.js:4659
wrappedCallback angular-1.0.0.min.js:6587
(anonymous function) angular-1.0.0.min.js:6622
Scope.$eval angular-1.0.0.min.js:7769
Scope.$digest angular-1.0.0.min.js:7641
Scope.$apply angular-1.0.0.min.js:7855
done angular-1.0.0.min.js:8844
completeRequest angular-1.0.0.min.js:8984
xhr.onreadystatechange
```

here is the code:

```
  //SHARE DATA BETWEEN CONTROLLERS
  c2dApp.factory("ShareData", function() {

    return {
      //ZipCode: function() {return ZipCode;},
      resList: function() {return ResList;}
    };

  });

  //CONTROLLERS: SEARCHLIST
  c2dApp.controller('SearchResultController', function($scope, ShareData) {
    //NEEDS THE RESTULT FROM SEARCH
  });

  //CONTROLLERS: SEARCH
  c2dApp.controller("SeachController", function($scope, $http, ShareData) {
    $scope.message = 'dit is search';
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.haveZip = false;

    $scope.searchForm = {};
    $scope.searchForm.zipCode = "";

    $scope.searchForm.getFormFieldCssClass = function(ngModelController) {
        //console.log("getting css class: " + ngModelController.$valid) ;
        if(ngModelController.$pristine) return "";
        return ngModelController.$valid ? "fieldValid" : "fieldInvalid";
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        //console.log("--> Submitting form");
        $http({

          url: "http://localhost/c2dapi/search",
          data: $scope.searchForm,
          method: 'POST',
          headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

        }).success(function(data){
          //console.log("OK", data);
          if (angular.equals(data[0], 'no_location_found')) {
            console.log('geen lokatie gevonden');
          }

          if (angular.equals(data[0], 'restaurants_found')) {
            console.log('restaurant lijst');
            console.log(data);
            ShareData.ResList() = data;  // <------ REturns ERROR
          }
        }).error(function(err){"ERR", console.log(err)});
    };
  });
```

//UPDATE
cshion awnser works partial

ShareData.ResList() = data;

```
returns the error ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

so i changed it to; `ShareData.ResList = data;`

now the json objects are found when i call  `ShareData.ResList`

but this is only after the post, i want to so something like

if (ShareData.ResList) {
}

the problem is that ShareData.ResList is never "undefined" but returns:

```
function () {
        return ResList;
      }
```

when its not set? i want it do return false.. how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between controllers , directives ,etc with Service or Factory.
Using factory:

```
c2dApp.factory("ShareData", function() {
 var ResList;
 return {
   resList: function() {return ResList;}
 };
```

});

In your controller:

```
ShareData.resList() = data
```

Comment: Hey, it works but now im have another problem, do u know how to fix this ? see update in question

Comment: you can try 2 functions inside your factory , something like this:
var Reslist;
return {
   getresList : function () {return Reslist},
   setrestList : function(data){ Restlist=data}
}
I hope that help you , im not a expert but i try to help.